# Non empty set and group

Tags: group-theory

Let $E$ be a non empty set. How to prove that there exists $\star:E\times E\rightarrow E$ for which $(E,\star)$ is a group?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: This is equivalent to the axiom of choice. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf

Answer (score 5):

If $E$ is finite, you can just identify $E$ with $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, where $n=|E|$.

If $E$ is countably infinite, you can similarly identify it with $\Bbb Z$ (or $\Bbb Q$ for that matter).
More generally, for *any* infinite cardinality of $E$, you can consider the set of groups with carrier sets $\subseteq E$, ordered by inclusion. Using Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal such group $M$. Conclude that $|M|>|E\setminus M|$ (and hence $|M|=|E|$, as desired) because otherwise you could build $M\hookrightarrow M\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\subseteq E$, contradicting maximality.